# how to use a `FasterRCNNObjectDetector` trained in matlab from flutter

Tags: flutter, matlab, tensorflow, tflite

I've trained a FasterRCNNObjectDetector as shown in the code below:

```
Tabulate your labeled growth truth data into a table





data4=load('labelsArrayLettucePrev.mat');

table1=table(data4.gTruth.DataSource.Source,data4.gTruth.LabelData.lettuce);
ObjectLoc=table1;




Training Option
% Training Option
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
        'MiniBatchSize', 1, ....
        'InitialLearnRate',1e-4, ...
        'MaxEpochs',13,...
        'CheckpointPath', tempdir, ...
        'executionEnvironment','gpu',...
        'Shuffle','every-epoch');    

Train Object Detector
% Train Faster RCNN detector.
 [detector, info] = trainFasterRCNNObjectDetector(ObjectLoc, "alexnet", options);
```

This gives me a .mat that i want to export as a tflite so that i can use my object detector in flutter with flutter_tflite, since the code is already built for a tflite model.